# How can I force Grunt to compile Sass even when no changes have been made?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I want grunt to compile sass every time grunt is executed if my Sass files haven't changed.  Sometimes the watcher fails to detect if the compiled result is different from the existing CSS file, and the only way to force it to compile is by editing one of the Sass files.

Grunt file:

```
/**
 * @file
 */
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // This is where we configure each task that we'd like to run.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    watch: {
      // This is where we set up all the tasks we'd like grunt to watch for changes.
      scripts: {
        files: ['js/source/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify'],
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        },
      },
      images: {
        files: ['images/source/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        tasks: ['imagemin'],
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        }
      },
      vector: {
        files: ['images/source/{,*/}*.svg'],
        tasks: ['svgmin'],
        options: {
          spawn: false,
        }
      },
      css: {
        files: ['sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass']
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      // This is for minifying all of our scripts.
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        mangle: false
      },
      my_target: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'js/source',
          src: '{,*/}*.js',
          dest: 'js/build'
        }]
      }
    },
    imagemin: {
      // This will optimize all of our images for the web.
      dynamic: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'images/source/',
          src: ['{,*/}*.{png,jpg,gif}' ],
          dest: 'images/optimized/'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      options: {
        plugins: [{
          removeViewBox: false
        }, {
          removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'images/source/',
          src: ['{,*/}*.svg' ],
          dest: 'images/optimized/'
        }]
      }
    },
    sass: {
      // This will compile all of our sass files
      // Additional configuration options can be found at https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        // This controls the compiled css and can be changed to nested, compact or compressed.
        outputStyle: 'expanded',
        precision: 5
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          'css/base/base.css': 'sass/base/base.sass',
          'css/components/components.css': 'sass/components/components.sass',
          'css/components/tabs.css': 'sass/components/tabs.sass',
          'css/components/messages.css': 'sass/components/messages.sass',
          'css/layout/layout.css': 'sass/layout/layout.sass',
          'css/theme/theme.css': 'sass/theme/theme.sass',
          'css/theme/print.css': 'sass/theme/print.sass'
        }
      }
    },
    browserSync: {
      dev: {
        bsFiles: {
          src : [
            'css/**/*.css',
            'templates/{,*/}*.twig',
            'images/optimized/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}',
            'js/build/{,*/}*.js',
            '*.theme'
          ]
        },
        options: {
          watchTask: true,
          // Change this to "true" if you'd like the css to be injected rather than a browser refresh. In order for this to work with Drupal you will need to install https://drupal.org/project/link_css keep in mind though that this should not be run on a production site.
          injectChanges: false
        }
      }
    },
  });
  // This is where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svgmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
  // Now that we've loaded the package.json and the node_modules we set the base path
  // for the actual execution of the tasks
  // grunt.file.setBase('/')
  // This is where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
  // Note: if you'd like to run and of the tasks individually you can do so by typing 'grunt mytaskname' alternatively
  // you can type 'grunt watch' to automatically track your files for changes.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync','watch']);
};
```

Comment: What is "when sass != css"  supposed to mean in this context here?  And why would you need the watcher to compile changes if none of the files have changed?

Comment: To make it clear when i run grunt at the current state it'll do nothing althoug sass is full of code and the css file aren't. It will make changes when i update a sass file but what I want is to tell grunt hey the current state of the sass files differs from the css file so do your magic, without editing a sass file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'browserSync',
    'sass',
    'watch',
]);
```

Simply register `sass` as a task to run when you type `grunt`.

If you do this and the sass files are still not giving you the results you want, then you need to revisit your `sass` task and make sure you're piping the files where you want them to go.

More cool options:

`newer`: When you run `grunt` you want sass to compile to CSS *only* if there is a difference between the new CSS and the old. In that case, try [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer). Appending `newer:taskyouwanttorun:option` will work.

`watch:sass`: You want sass to compile during a `watch` based on something besides changing one of the sass files. Easy, just set up a watch task that looks for whatever file you want to modify, image/javascript/html/whatever and set the task as `sass`

Comment: The plain and simple truth of the matter is... you're right. And being that I coincidentally answered the _wrong_ 2 questions first instead of the correct, much simpler question actually being asked, it hits the mark twice as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D Sry english is not my native language didn't want to confuse somebody.